Argumentation of Spivak's choice of epsilon in integrability proof
I have a question about the choice of the bound for uniform continuity (why is it $\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$) in Spivak's proof of integrability of continuous functions on $[a, b]$.
Here is his proof:
Notice, first, that $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, because it is continuous on $[a, b]$. To prove that $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$, we want to use Theorem 2, and show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a partition $P$ of $[a, b]$ such that
$$
U(f, P) - L(f, P) < \epsilon.
$$
Now we know, by Theorem 1 of the Appendix to Chapter 8, that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a, b]$. So there is some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ and $y$ in $[a, b]$,
$$
\text{if } |x - y| < \delta, \text{ then } |f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}.
$$
The trick is simply to choose a partition $P = {t_0, \ldots, t_n}$ such that each $|t_i - t_{i-1}| < \delta$. Then for each $i$ we have
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)} \qquad \text{for all } x, y \text{ in } [t_{i-1}, t_i],
$$
and it follows easily that
$$
M_i - m_i \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)} < \frac{\epsilon}{b-a}.
$$
Since this is true for all $i$, we then have
$$
U(f, P) - L(f, P) = \sum_{i=1}^n (M_i - m_i)(t_i - t_{i-1}) \
< \frac{\epsilon}{b-a} \sum_{i=1}^n t_i - t_{i-1} \
= \frac{\epsilon}{b-a} \cdot b - a \
= \epsilon,
$$
which is what we wanted. $\blacksquare$

It's not clear to me why he picks $\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$, since it seems he is not using this fact.
The only reason I can see is the fact that $M_i - m_i \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$ is not a strict inequality, which allows us to then state it is strictly less than $\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$
And, in fact, I am not sure why $M_i - m_i \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$ instead of $M_i - m_i < \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$ since we have that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$ which would even further make his choice of the bound peculiar.

It is for tidiness. Otherwise he would have had to choose some $\lambda < {\epsilon \over b-a}$ and then argue in terms of $\lambda$. His goal is to prove the result, not to use minimal 'slop' in the choice of parameters.

I don't follow the lambda argument. Why didn't he pick $\frac{\epsilon}{b - a}$? What I am saying is that I don't understand why he needs to pick $\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$ instead.

He doesn't need to.

while your first comment was probably intended to be helpful, which I cannot grasp. I am almost certain the second was to just confuse me haha :)

I am not trying to confuse. He does not need to pick that specific number. But he did and the proof works.

See The confusion about the proof of if function is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$,then it is integrable.

this looks like exactly what I need, thank you

I have just realised that you actually answered that question @peek-a-boo :) Your answer has been invaluable! Thank you.

@nz_ $(\ddot{\smile})$

First, if $a < b$, then $a \leq b$. See: The confusion about the proof of if function is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$,then it is integrable. All 12 statements in the answer are logically equivalent.
Second, the reason he picked $\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$ was purely to have something that is smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$, which is what he needed to factor out of the summation to show that the whole summation can be made less than $\epsilon$. As such, he could have picked anything that is smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$.
